# Matlab in a Chrome extension (via Java compiler) possible?

Tags: java, matlab, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to integrate a *Matlab* program into a Chrome extension using the *Matlab Builder JA*?

Essentially, I have a computational tool in Matlab that I want to make more user-friendly and widely-available for other researchers with few or no programming skills. The best way to do this seems to be deploying it on the web--and, since I don't have access to a web server, in a Chrome extension. In order to deploy Matlab on the web via Java, it seems I need to upload the JRE or JDK and do a lot of other configurations on a server, like in http://www.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/web-deployment.html *(need a Matlab account to view)*.

Any workarounds for the extension that don't require a web server? Or other ideas to distribute my package to non-programmers so that they can use it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can only run javascript with extensions. look into a native app maybe

Comment: Why a Chrome extension? Just make a runnable jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in a similar situation, and I solved it in a slightly more elegant way than trying to play with web plugins:

In order to make the functions of my package accessible to non-programmers, I built a very simple GUI using `guide` in matlab, which allowed users to open data files, choose processing parameters, run the analysis, and export the results. Guide is very simple to use, and there are some good tutorials online. Then in terms of distributing it, I packaged all the necessary matlab files into a single folder, and then wrote a bash script (linux/mac) that would copy the files into a sensible directory, make a shortcut in `/usr/bin/` (so that the GUI could be opened directly from the command line by running `scatter_analysis` without invoking any other display from matlab), and finally make a double-clickable shortcut on the desktop. The only prerequisite is that the user has matlab installed already.

I presume you're using windows, which I know nothing about, but I think it's likely that you can come up with a similar solution on the windows platform with far less effort than wrestling with web plugins? Unfortunately I cannot share my code - I'm in the process of selling it and any disclosure would violate the terms of the sale.

Comment: Thanks! Good advice :)